# How to make helpers for models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this private method in my User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :fullname, :password, :username
  has_secure_password
  before_create { generate_token(:remember_token) }
  .
  .
  private
    def generate_token(col)
      begin
        self[col] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
      end while User.exists?(col => self[col])
    end

end
```

How can i make generate_token available In other models? 
Thanks

Comment: just create a new class, what's the problem?

Comment: A class that extends the user model or the ar:base?

Comment: Sorry i'm new to rails but i know a few oo languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

many options here are some:

- use a plain, simple ruby module.

  ```
  module TokenRememberable
    private
    def generate_token(col)
      begin
        self[col] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
      end while User.exists?(col => self[col])
    end 
  end

  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    include TokenRememberable
    before_create { generate_token(:remember_token) }
  end
  ```
- for more complex functionnality, use ActiveSupport::Concern :

  ```
  module TokenRememberable
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    # thanks to Concern, this block wil be evaluated 
    # in the context of the including class
    included do 
      before_create { generate_token(:remember_token) }
    end

    private
    def generate_token(col)
      begin
        self[col] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
      end while self.class.exists?(col => self[col])
    end 
  end

  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    include TokenRememberable
  end
  ```
- extract the functionnality in a dedicated class, and possibly use composition

  ```
  # we only need a class method here, but you can also build 
  # full-fledged objects as you need
  class TokenGenerator 
    def self.generate_token
      # your generation logic here
    end  
  end

  class User
    def after_initialize
      @token_generator = TokenGenerator # or TokenGenerator.new( self ), for instance
    end
    attr_reader :token_generator
    delegate :generate_token, to: :token_generator # optionnaly use delegation
  end
  ```

**NOTE** :
this is not really a rails issue, more a Ruby one. You should document yourself more on the language you are using... Modules are a very common idiom. I can give you some good reference books if you need

Comment: I hate modules, btw they are more and more disregarded. They just hide complexity. You should favor independent classes, easily testable.

Comment: i agree that they hide complexity, but sometimes they are just right. I do hear what you say about testing, though. What do you mean by "they are more and more disregarded" ? By whom ?

Comment: ps - i also agree that composition is a better solution... but still, modules _are_ a common idiom and the OP does not seem to know about their existence...

Comment: it is, but it bloats ActiveRecord objects and push them to the god object direction. Ok to use modules when you want to share code accross classes, not to extract code from a class.

Comment: thanks for the link. Indeed, it echoes some of my concerns these last weeks... I've been thinking that most rails models gleefully violate SRP and end up like logic behemoths. To be honest, I still consider myself a newbie in programming (btw i think we met before, when i started lurking around on SO) and i don't know what to do with such insights (as i don't know what to do with DCI concepts, for instance).

Comment: I tend to abstract my code more and more, my Mongoid classes tend to be smaller and smaller. Use Service Objects, Presenters. try to avoid callbacks, observers. You will think everything differently. Thus you'll have small and easily testable objects with few responsibilities

Comment: yup... i wish i had the latitude to try all this stuff at my job :D

Comment: :) once your app explodes and the cost of change soars, you should be given the reins to work properly... but convince your CTO to make the move when it's still easy.

Comment: Learnt to use all the different methods, seems like i gained a lot of ruby knowledge today haha. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

a few approaches:

- slightly dependent:

do:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_create { User::Helpers.new(self).generate_token(:remember_token) }

  class Helpers < Struct.new(:user)
    def generate_token(col)
      begin
        user.send("#{col}=", SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64)
      end while User.exists?(col => user.send(col))
    end
  end
end
```

- independent: don't pass the `user` object to the class, just make  the method render a random token and assign it from the model.

Comment: Is that helper class meant in the User class?

Comment: as you wish, really, you're completely free, was just an example since they seem to be very tied. You can crate a new file or keep it there